# getString from strings.xml in AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

I have this in a normal activity:

```
tv.setText(this.getString(R.string.week1));
```

I think

```
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview,"something");
```

is the equivalent to

```
tv.setText("something");
```

How do I getString from strings.xml in AppWidgetProvider?

There is probably a really easy solution but I tried using google and I'm new to android...

Comment: I do not know how to "How do I getString from strings.xml in AppWidgetProvider?" but I think you try to get string from strings.xml

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, when you get a hold of a Context you can just call

```
context.getString(resIdHere);
```

onEnable(), onDisable(), onReceive() and onUpdate() methods all pass context reference in to their definitions by default.

Hope this helps,

-serkan

Answer (score 4):

I do not know how to "How do I getString from strings.xml in AppWidgetProvider?" but I think you try to get string from strings.xml

and that could be done like this.

```
String s = getResources().getString(R.string.-yourString);
```